# TCP error 10055: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: java, wcf, tomcat, mtom

I am getting this TCP error: `(10055: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full) occurred while transmitting data.`

Apparently I start getting this error if I try to transfer any file over 50 MB.
I am using WCF. I have web services written in Java/Tomcat.

Could it be a problem in server-side configurations?

The server is Tomcat, can you tell me which value to customize in that case?

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWebService1SoapHttpPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="4000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999"
        messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedRequest"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://[IP]/Transfer"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyWebService1SoapHttpPortBinding"
      contract="Transfer" name="MyWebService1SoapHttpPort" />
</client>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing your `maxBufferSize`?

Comment: i have tried this
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

yet invain . i still think it must be tomcat configuration issues,. as if it was IIS i would have to change teh maxrequestlendth parameter for large bninary

Comment: It is  windows config/resource issue, the problem is not with your app. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your error message and [google it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS375US375&q=A+TCP+error+(10055:+An+operation+on+a+socket+could+not+be+performed+because+the+system+lacked+sufficient+buffer+space+or+because+a+queue+was+full)+&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) you will find many answers.

A TCP error (10055: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full)

Here is one.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271

Comment: Thanks Romain , 
If googling would be effective in this case , i wouldnt be here, still i want to know how can i avoid this error , and still transfer the data over webservices to Java. I have a WCF server and a client and they works perfect even for 250 mb transfer, yet as soon as i shift my solution to Java webservices i start getting error even at 50 mb. I am sure i am using right DataHandler type as per metro , Jax-ws. Anyway I wish there is any expert opinion.

Thanks for you answer

Comment: I believe its interoperability which causing problem between Java and WCF